# 2-in-1 Laptop tablet mode issues after installing a fresh version of Ubuntu

Tags: asus, rotate-monitor

Currently, I am using a 2-in-1 Asus Model TP500LA and I decided to install a new version of Ubuntu (14.04). However, when I freshly installed it, I notice that the computer is unable to go into "tablet mode". Specifically, I believe that the rotation sensors and accelerometer in the computer is not able to detect whether I changed the physical orientation of the laptop like a regular tablet. I am not sure how to fix this problem since I am completely new to Linux and Ubuntu.

Do you guys know how to fix this problem?

Here are the drivers installed into my computer BTW:

```
dummy@dummy-TP500LA:~$ lsmod

Module                  Size  Used by
hid_generic            12548  0 
ctr                    13049  2 
ccm                    17773  2 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46368  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    65580  1 
rfcomm                 69160  0 
bnep                   19624  2 
bluetooth             391136  10 bnep,rfcomm
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
hid_multitouch         17407  0 
uvcvideo               80885  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         40664  1 uvcvideo
videodev              134688  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
intel_rapl             18773  0 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
intel_powerclamp       14705  0 
coretemp               13435  0 
kvm_intel             143187  0 
kvm                   455835  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       14289  0 
crc32_pclmul           13113  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13216  0 
aesni_intel            55624  4 
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    13286  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
glue_helper            13990  1 aesni_intel
usbhid                 52659  0 
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20359  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
hid                   106148  3 hid_multitouch,hid_generic,usbhid
snd_hda_intel          56451  5 
joydev                 17381  0 
snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
serio_raw              13462  0 
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102099  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
rtsx_pci_ms            18151  0 
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
arc4                   12608  2 
memstick               16966  1 rtsx_pci_ms
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
rt2800pci              23116  0 
wmi                    19177  0 
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
parport_pc             32701  0 
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
i915                  784207  7 
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
ppdev                  17671  0 
rt2800lib             115585  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00mmio             13564  1 rt2800pci
i2c_designware_platform    12960  0 
rt2x00pci              13287  1 rt2800pci
i2c_designware_core    14768  1 i2c_designware_platform
rt2x00lib              79430  4 rt2x00pci,rt2800lib,rt2800pci,rt2x00mmio
video                  19476  1 i915
mac80211              630653  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00pci,rt2800lib
drm_kms_helper         55071  1 i915
snd                    69322  21 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
lpc_ich                21080  0 
drm                   303102  6 i915,drm_kms_helper
mei_me                 18627  0 
mei                    82276  1 mei_me
cfg80211              484040  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
mac_hid                13205  0 
soundcore              12680  1 snd
crc_ccitt              12707  1 rt2800lib
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
eeprom_93cx6           13344  1 rt2800pci
eeprom                 12841  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         23274  0 
ahci                   25819  3 
psmouse               106714  0 
libahci                32716  1 ahci
r8169                  67581  0 
rtsx_pci               46202  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
mii                    13934  1 r8169
```